# How to cope with 10,000 people accessing a webserver in an hour?

Tags: mysql, web-server, server-crashes

I have a share hosting, and I charge 100$/year to host company websites. Those websites have a maximum of 2000 person per month access onto the site, mostly Wordpress. So everything is fine until a person in Facebook, with 300000 friends talk about the website. Even if just 10% go see the site, it's 30,000 people at the same time accessing the site and, the site crashed.  Then after 1 hour, it's back on...

So the question, how best to cope with that ?

Comment: what do you mean by "crashed"?  What exactly happened?  Was something killed by OOM?  was it just unusably slow?

Comment: You need to introduce layers of cache to all the wordpress websites affected. For example, Varnish and modified Wordpress headers can speed up the website up to 1GBps output without crashing, you just move varnish to another ip number and the domains, and forward traffic to wordpress server.

Comment: On shared hosting you cannot "varnish" anything... your not a that level. and the crash said : maximum ressources used, try again later !

Comment: @menardmam: Your question isn't a good fit for this site. We would normally expect questions to come from people who have the atuthority and administrative privileges to "fix" the "problem" which precludes users of shared hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to cope with a 10 000 person accession server in one hour?

Design a solution that can handle the load spikes. 10,000 hits in an hour is really only 167 requests per second. That's a decent amount, but it's not a massive hurdle to overcome.

Profile your app. See what part dies when this happens. Fix it.

Comment: profiling apps... i have no idea what this is !

Comment: @menardmam How are you a programmer and don't know how to profile them? Itsn't that Programming 101?